# Watch website and wait for events

Tags: javascript

I want to analyze a website that is not mine.
So, I want to use Javascript to do it at my end in the browser.
After I click a button on the website I want to trigger a timer and as soon as a notification from the website comes back, the timer should stop and save the notification that came back.
How can I do this the easiest way?

I cannot give you the link to the website, because it's hosted in a private network.

My first question would be, how I can log all events that are triggered on a website to the console, so I know the name of the button I want to wait for.

Thanks!
dave

Comment: What kind of events are you talking about watching for?

Comment: I will assume you want to watch regular DOM events, in which case I will say: it's not possible? Or I am not aware that it is.

Comment: It's a button that I want to watch. If this button is clicked the timer should start. And then after a couple of seconds the website will give back a notification at the top of the screen about wether it was successful or not. The timer should stop with the notification.

Comment: So add a click handler to the button and poll the DOM looking for the new element to show up.

Comment: Why would you analyze a website that's not yours? If they don't provide an API, maybe it should not be analyzed. Sound sketchy to me!

Comment: The description is way too vague. MAke a print screen of the site, show some source code ;)

Comment: @JonasdeHerdt that's just what I got as a task. Not my choice. The website is used by my company but developed by some other company.

Comment: You can use the console to look through the DOM, data and events. Maybe you need to look at plugin development for your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## All events on a specific DOM node:

To see all the events for a specific DOMnode, or window (only works on chrome i believe, didnt test it elsewhere):

```
getEventListeners(window)
```

this will give you an object with all the events, then you can intercept them with

```
window.addEventListener(eventName, fn, true);
```

## The whole application:

this way your event will be called whenever an event on that node is triggered (window in this case)

if you want absolutely all events on the whole app, you can achieve it with using something like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API#monitorEvents.28object.5B.2C_types.5D.29)

## Specific event on a specific element:

if you want a button click only, you can do the following:

```
var specificButton = document.querySelector('#specific-button')
specificButton.addEventListener('click', function() {});
```

## Implementation:

if you do not own the sourcecode, you can use something like `greasemonkey` or `tampermonkey` to inject your javascript into the page.

if you are using it on a server, you can use [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) to parse the returned html from the get request, and apply queries on it, but you will lose the ability for listening to live events from io devices.

Comment: the button doesn't have a specific id.
it just says `"data-protractor-id": "example-button"`
how can I access this button? I just know how to access a button with a specific id or class.

Comment: @dave check the selector specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-representation.
 you can run `document.querySelector('button[data-protractor-id="example-button"]');`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, the easiest option I see is to open your browser developer tools and using the console get the button (document.getElementById, i.e.) and change its onclick callback, including a call to the old callback in your new callback, and trigger your timer.

To intercept the response to this button (I assume that it triggers a network request), you'll have to analyze a bit the code of the web to see how you can detect it.

You could also edit the website javascript throught "Sources" tab of your browser's dev tools.

It's an idea. I have never done something like that. I have to admit that it sounds a little weird to me.

Comment: this is too much work, you can simply add a new event listener on the element, and trigger the timer. setting the 3rd optional parameter in the listener to true will trigger the new event first, having it false will trigger it last.